# Mootools domready called twice

Tags: joomla, mootools, domready

I can't seem to work out why my domready function is being called twice.
`window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    alert('Ready!!111');
}`

Its on a joomla 1.6 installation (mootools 1.3) with a joomlart t3 template and a couple of ja modules. Other than that I have my own custom component, nothing special. With a bunch of code that runs when dom is ready. I'v spent many an hour trying to work out why domready is executed twice but to no avail.

Link: http://elwood.visualdomainhosting.com/

Anyone got any ideas on what may be causing this? Or experienced something similar?

Edit:
After some further testing on PC in Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari I found the issue is only present on Chrome and Safari. Being a Mac user using both Chrome and Safari for my dev I assumed it was an issues in all browsers (stupid assumption on my part). I'm running Chrome 12.0.742.112 and Safari 5.0.5 (6533.21.1) if you still dont get the same results as I described above.

Comment: you have 3 domready blocks called - 2 through js37595.js and 1 through inline js on the page. ja.more and milkbox add a callback. can you add a console.log call to "domready running" or something to illustrate it, seems fine in chrome canary v13

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the template is using a bunch of Javascript to handle layout functions, not a good practice for just these reasons. I'd consider another template/rework the functionality in PHP.